# es5-shim or chrome frame for making angular apps work in IE

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-frame

I am developing rich frontend apps which will be used by users running IE 8 and above. I am using angular.js as my frontend framework.

I currently see two choices using es5shim or google chrome frame. What I am not able to discern are the differences between both.

As I understand that es5-shim monkey patches the js engine, and is much more lighter as it doesnt require the user to download and install.

What does chrome frame provide over es5-shim, and which is recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome Frame is a application, and need user to install it, es5-shim is JavaScript code, you just need to include it.

If you want to use AngularJS in in IE, you should read this: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie. Long in short, include es5-shim(optional but really useful) and JSON polyfill.